# PHP array_merge is particularly slow and memory intensive when it is used in a loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, array-merge

I have a problem... I have done some research and I have been told that having an array_merge in a foreach can be particularly slow and memory intensive and i need an alternative for this block of code. But i'm not sure what is the best course to take

Can anyone help?

```
/**
 * Parse long itrative tags
 *
 * Return array of matches for iterative tag pattern e.g. {%label%} to output the document label on this iteration of the loop
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  array
 */

function parse_long_iterative_tags($text)
{
    $pattern = "/{%(?P<type>[A-Za-z0-9_?!]+):\((?P<name>.+)\)[\s]*(?P<attributes>[A-Za-z0-9\s_,:?.\/\-\|\(\)]*?){[\s]*(?P<content>(.*?[\s]*)*)[\s]*\}[\s]*end\\1\%}/";
    preg_match_all($pattern,$text,$matches);
    if(!empty($matches['content'])):
        $nested = implode("",$matches['content']);
        $sub_matches =  $this->parse_long_iterative_tags($nested);
        foreach($matches as $k=>$v):
            $matches[$k] = array_merge($matches[$k],$sub_matches[$k]);
        endforeach;
        return $matches;
    else:
        return $matches;
    endif;
    return $matches;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: It might be easier to understand what you are doing if we could see an example of the data being processed. Otherwise you are just going to get a bunch of guesses

Comment: Yup. Because so far that I see you could simply just do $matches[$k][]=$sub_matches[$k]

Comment: I would like to know what $matches['content'] has so we can test

Comment: Had to step away for a few minutes but didn't edit in time: Just do a sub loop through the sub matches and append like so: foreach($submatches[$k] as $value) $matches[$k][]=$value

Comment: https://github.com/dseguy/clearPHP/blob/master/rules/no-array_merge-in-loop.md

Comment: It's to look for any tags that get parsed on a page and then return with the correct output for each loop it goes through. I have updated the code, hopefully it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just running it with a dual loop like so instead of

```
foreach($matches as $k=>$v):
   $matches[$k] = array_merge($matches[$k],$sub_matches[$k]);
```

You would do:

```
foreach($matches as $k=>$v)
  foreach($submatches[$k] as $j=>$v2)
   $matches[$k][$j] = $v2;
```

It should roughly represent the same output, but then again you should try posting a var dump of the resulting `$matches` array to be sure.